# what will be time complexity if we divide array in log(n) instead of 2?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to improve algorithm for my project.instead of dividing array into 2 part I am planning to divide array in log(n) and remaining part (i.e. (logn-1)(n/logn) ).For example: 
for n=64 
log(n)=6
I will take pass over array and divide it in such way that one part will contain logn=6 and other part will have remaining (64-6)=58 element and I will recursively do that for 6 and 58 till I get 2. i.e. in next pass I will divide 58 in logn=5 and 53 element and for 6 I will divide it into log n=2 and other part will have 4 element.

what will be  time complexity in the end?I am getting nlogn but what will be constant factor along with that ?Can any one help me to find constant factor with nlogn ?

Comment: It sounds like you are still dividing the array in 2 parts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes but instead of dividing in 1/2 parts I am trying to divide log(n) and (logn-1)(n/logn) parts.what will be time complexity in the end?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if I divide them in 1/2 parts then constant factor will be c=1 with nlogn .What will be constant factor if we divide then in  log(n) and (logn-1)(n/logn) parts ?

Comment: It seems that it will take more steps than an even divide, which is why algorithms like mergesort use an even split.  Also, depending on the value of `n`, the split may not be balanced on both sides.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen assume that n is even or odd according to logn value .I know that it is more than 1 and less than 2.I am not able to calculate theoretically what will be the value of c in cnlogn ?

Comment: The short answer is that it depends on the algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem. Master Theorem for Unequal Subproblems may help, however, that only talks about linear "unequalness": https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~hal/allmaster.pdf

Comment: @kfx I tried master theorem but I am not getting answer that why I asked here.would you like to calculate that constant factor ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example:

```
n=64 log(n)=6
```

Seems like what you mean is log2(n) (not log10(n)).

Since the number of n is integer, for such calculation using 2^n as divider, the best is using **right bitwise shift** operator (That is, in most of the languages, it will look like this: >>) You may consider using this to speed up your calculation.

This way, you get faster way to split your array into 2. With your formulation.

Now come to your question. The time complexity may or may not be reduced if you use such division of the array element at all, depending on what is the algorithm in question.

For example, if the algorithm is simple addition between x numbers. By dividing it into smaller arrays recursively, it doesn't reduce the complexity. On the contrary, it will add the time complexity.

But if your algorithm is, let say, to sort something based on n element, then the reccursive division of an array might be a good idea. In this case, it may reduce the complexity since the number or elements in the algorithm determines the number of actions.

So, the **bottom line** to know the complexity here is how the algorithm look like, and not how to divide the elements of the algorithm into 2 or into log2(n) recursively.

Comment: yes I know that If I divide array in logn and remaining part it will increase the complexity but how much ?I tried taking example I got between 1.3 and 1.4.I want to find It theoretically.would you like to calculate that constant factor ?

Comment: What I mean is, we cannot know whether the division of array will add or reduce the computational time. It depends on how the algorithm in question look like, not the division of array into exact two numbers or one is bigger another is smaller. It doesn't matter at all. What matter most is how the algorithm look like, what algorithm you are talking here. Then the complexity addition/reduction can be known.

Comment: Assume that instead of dividing array in 2 part if we divide array in logn and other part in case of quicksort then what will be time complexity ?

Comment: Quicksort takes dynamic pivoting, and that is its strength. If you now make it into 2 elements left, then it will perform the same as bubble sort in the bottom iteration. I don't think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of an algorithm with such a division is expressed by this recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n - log(n)) + T(log(n)) + D(n)
```

where `D(n)` is the complexity of the "merge" step.

To create an asymptotic lower bound on this complexity, first notice that the second term `T(log(n))` is very small. We can ignore it in further analysis and still getting quite accurate lower bound estimate.

As for the first term `T(n - log(n))`, we can notice that the sum

```
log(n) + log(n -log(n)) + log(n-log(n)-log(n-log(n))) + ... (k terms in total)
```

is smaller than `k log(n)`. To reduce `n` to zero by repeatedly subtracting `log(n)` from it, `k = n / log(n)` steps must taken. Therefore there are `n / log(n)` steps of average size `D(n/2)` (because the input size varies from `n` to `0`; on the average, the input size is half the original input size).

Now let's consider a specific example. Assuming `D(n) = O(n)` as in quicksort or merge sort, `D(n/2) = O(n)` as well, and the total complexity is `O(n / log(n)) O(n) = O(n^2 / log n)`.

In short, this method of division is not very good: it turns algorithms of `O(n log n)` complexity to algorithms of almost quadratic complexity.